# How to use the Stacked CTE or Calendar Table in a date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loops, date

I have this loop where it shows all the dates in a separate query based from the two (2) parameters given - `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. The goal is to make this in a single query result.

I read some suggestion to change it into a Stacked CTE or use a calendar table. But, I am a total newbie SQL Server development.

Can you please help how I can transform this query?

Any inputs are appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME,
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2020-06-01'
SET @EndDate = '2020-06-05'
SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate

WHILE (@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CAST(CurrentDate as DATE) AS CalendarDate, 
        currencyId, country,
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays <= 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS notOverdue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays >= 1 AND overdueDays <= 5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS _1_5_days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays >= 6 AND overdueDays <= 15 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS _6_15_days, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays >= 16 AND overdueDays <= 30 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS _16_30_days, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays >= 31 AND overdueDays <= 60 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS _31_60_days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays >= 61 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS _61_days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN overdueDays > 0 then amount else 0 end)  as totalOverdue
from (
  SELECT datediff(day, vp.maturity_date, @CurrentDate) AS overdueDays, 
        vp.currency_id AS currencyId, 
        SUM(vp.amount) AS amount, 
        b.trading_country_code AS country
    FROM verification_package vp
    INNER JOIN buyer b ON vp.buyer_id=b.buyer_id
  WHERE (vp.date_fully_paid IS NULL OR  (vp.date_fully_paid IS NOT NULL AND vp.date_fully_paid>@CurrentDate))
    AND vp.maturity_date IS NOT NULL
    and (b.active_to_date is null or b.active_to_date >= @CurrentDate) and b.active_from_date <=@CurrentDate
    AND b.program_id IN ('PRG_ID')
  GROUP BY vp.maturity_date, vp.currency_id, b.trading_country_code

  UNION ALL

  SELECT datediff(day, vp.maturity_date,@CurrentDate) AS overdueDays,
        vp.currency_id AS currencyId, -SUM(COALESCE(pb.amount, 0)) AS amount, b.trading_country_code as country
    FROM verification_package vp
    INNER JOIN etb2.payment_booking pb ON vp.verification_package_id=pb.verification_package_id
    INNER JOIN etb2.payment p ON pb.payment_id=p.id
    INNER JOIN buyer b ON vp.buyer_id=b.buyer_id
  WHERE (vp.date_fully_paid IS NULL OR  (vp.date_fully_paid IS NOT NULL AND vp.date_fully_paid>@CurrentDate))
    AND vp.maturity_date IS NOT NULL
    AND (p.id IS NULL OR p.value_date<=@CurrentDate)
    and (b.active_to_date is null or b.active_to_date >= @CurrentDate) and b.active_from_date <=@CurrentDate
    AND b.program_id IN (@ProgramID)
  GROUP BY vp.maturity_date,vp.currency_id , b.trading_country_code
) rawData
group by currencyId, country
order by currencyId, country;

    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @CurrentDate); /*increment current date*/
END
```

Here is the current OUTPUT (in separate SQL statement/result):

[image: QUERY RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

The calendar table is a good suggestion. You can find plenty of examples how to build one online.  Once you have it you can do something like this (You didn't give any sample data so I didn't test this and I only used part of your query, but it shows you how to do it I think.)

Basically you join the calender table and use the date in the calendar table for you DATEDIFF instead of the @CurrentDate.  So no more need for a loop.

```
SELECT datediff(day, vp.maturity_date,cal.theDate) AS overdueDays,
        vp.currency_id AS currencyId, -SUM(COALESCE(pb.amount, 0)) AS amount, b.trading_country_code as country
FROM verification_package vp
INNER JOIN etb2.payment_booking pb ON vp.verification_package_id=pb.verification_package_id
INNER JOIN etb2.payment p ON pb.payment_id=p.id
INNER JOIN buyer b ON vp.buyer_id=b.buyer_id

INNER JOIN myCalendarTable cal
    ON cal.theDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

WHERE (vp.date_fully_paid IS NULL OR  (vp.date_fully_paid IS NOT NULL AND vp.date_fully_paid>cal.theDate))
AND vp.maturity_date IS NOT NULL
AND (p.id IS NULL OR p.value_date<=cal.theDate)
and (b.active_to_date is null or b.active_to_date >= cal.theDate) and b.active_from_date <=cal.theDate
AND b.program_id IN (@ProgramID)
GROUP BY vp.maturity_date,vp.currency_id , b.trading_country_code
```